# how to add google adsens to an django web app

Tags: python, django, django-templates, adsense, django-sekizai

i'm trying to add google adsense to my django webapp but when i try i've got this error "website have no content".

if somedbody done this before can you explain to me please. i've seen maybe solution like sekizai or django ads to install in a project but i'm not able to install it because i don't understand everything.

maybe i don't put tag at the good place in my template but there's not a lot of informations on the sekizai website and it look to be necesarry to use adsense in django app.

thanks for help.

Comment: have you implemented the same, I also dont know how to implement the same